# Error: ActiveX Component Can't Create Object Scripting.FileSystemObject

Tags: vbscript, activex, filesystemobject

I have a simple vbs-file on my drive c: with following content:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

When I'm trying to launch it, I get error

> c:\fso.vbs(1, 1) Microsoft VBScript
>   runtime error: ActiveX component can't
>   create object:
>   'Scripting.FileSystemObject'

I tried to login as admin and execute `wscript -regserver`, but didn't help.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you are logged in as Admin, please have a look in registry for `Scripting.FileSystemObject` under HKCR.

If you can not find this PROGID then you are missing the required files or the component is disabled (not registered).

`Scripting.FileSystemObject` is implemented in *scrrun.dll*.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I reregistered  scrrun'dll regsvr32 /i "c:\windows\system32\scrrun.dll" and it works! Thanks!

Comment: Also disable you virusscanner!

Comment: If you get an error message "sccrun.dll was loaded, but the DllInstall entry point was not found" then run just run:
regsvr32 "c:\windows\system32\scrrun.dll"

Comment: I just run regsvr32 "c:\windows\system32\scrrun.dll" but then in VB I get same error.

Answer (score 1):

If re-registering scrrun.dll doesn't fix it, you might have to re-register a lot of other dependencies. The easiest way to do that is with MS Fixit 50123:
http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9666880
Run that, then try your FSO call again. This is the only thing that worked for me on a couple client computers that had various fake AV programs and reg cleaners.

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore. Is that one correct? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/sbs/windows/fix-windows-update-errors-18b693b5-7818-5825-8a7e-2a4a37d6d787

Answer (score 0):

In my case `ProgId` attribute on the COM component class was misspelled:

`[ProgId("XXX")]`