# Is it possible to check if a csv file has any data in it from VBA?

Tags: csv, file, ms-access, vba

Is it possible to check if a csv file has any data in it from VBA??
I want to import CSV file to access. It works fine if there is data in the CSV file but error occurs when there is no data in the CSV file.

Comment: If you give us a snippet of the code you're currently using, then the help we can give you will be less generic and more specific to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [FileLen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262742(VS.60).aspx) function:

`If FileLen("C:\your_dir\file_to_read.csv") = 0 Then MsgBox "Csv file is empty"`

Comment: Thanks @Fionnuala. Your suggestion would have worked well too, however sometimes you find that the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` object isn't always available. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457000/error-activex-component-cant-create-object-scripting-filesystemobject)